# Scrape web content from dynamically loaded page (infinite scroll)

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to collect all image filenames from this website: https://www.shipspotting.com/

I have already collected a python dict `cat_dict` of all the category names and their id numbers. So my strategy is to iterate through every category page, call the data loading API and save it's response for every page.

I have identified https://www.shipspotting.com/ssapi/gallery-search as the request URL which loads the next page of content. However, when I request this URL with the requests library, I get a 404. What do I need to do to obtain the correct response in loading the next page of content?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cat_page = 'https://www.shipspotting.com/photos/gallery?category='

for cat in cat_dict:
   cat_link = cat_page + str(cat_dict[cat])
   headers = {
   "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:96.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/96.0",
   "Referer": cat_link
}

   response = requests.get('https://www.shipspotting.com/ssapi/gallery-search', headers=headers)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
```

https://www.shipspotting.com/photos/gallery?category=169 is an example page (`cat_link`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you scroll the page down, a new request to server is being made (a POST one, with a certain payload). You can verify this in Dev tools, Network tab.

The following works:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

### put the following code in a for loop based on a number of pages 
### [total number of ship photos]/[12], or async it ... your choice

data = {"category":"","perPage":12,"page":2} 
r = requests.post('https://www.shipspotting.com/ssapi/gallery-search', data = data)
print(r.json())
```

This returns a json response:

```
{'page': 1, 'items': [{'lid': 3444123, 'cid': 172, 'title': 'ELLBING II', 'imo_no': '0000000',....}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idenntified url contains data via API as post method and infinity scroll makes the next pages meaning pagination from api's payload data.

Working code along with response 200

```
import requests

api_url= 'https://www.shipspotting.com/ssapi/gallery-search'
headers={'content-type': 'application/json'}
payload= {"category":"","perPage":12,"page":1}

for payload['page'] in range(1,7):
    res=requests.post(api_url,headers=headers,json=payload)
    for item in res.json()['items']:
        title=item['title']
        print(title)
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the image file names, and perhaps the images, here's what I did, worked for me on another site. I went to your ship website, and opened Inspector in Edge (lots of other browsers will have the same tools). I selected to see "Network" requests, and set the filter to look at "Fetch/XHR". Then I refreshed the page, and started scrolling down. There would be a "latest-photos" network request that happens when you get to the bottom of the page. I kept hitting "end" to get to the end of the newly loaded items and allow the site to load more. After I got tired of hitting the "end" button, I clicked on the last "latest-photos" entry in the network list, right clicked, and selected "copy all URLs". I pasted them into a text editor, and found about 800 links to different large photos, all formatted like this:
https://www.shipspotting.com/photos/middle/9/9/2/3691299.jpg?cb=0
I had been trying to use perl to scrape photos from a web page that loads infinitely, and just couldn't make it work, and came up with this solution, at least for the web site you're interested in.
Here are two screenshots from my work:
[1]: http://app25.com/shipspotting_1.jpg
[2]: http://app25.com/shipspotting_2.jpg